# How can private member variables in C++ be simulated in C?

Tags: c

Can private member variables (as in C++) be implemented in C and how can this can be achieved?  I thought about static global variables limiting the scope of the variable just to the file where it is defined, but then how would one access it from other files? Is there a way to implement private member variables in C?

Comment: I think static level vars in the source file is the best you can do, or using an opaque type

Comment: Just don't tell that there's a global to anyone else, and they won't access it. Needs a really obscure name though to avoid name-collisions.

Comment: C++ is written in C in the same way that English is written in Anglo-Saxon.

Comment: You could use *opaque* pointers to hide the members from the world.

Comment: C is a low-level system language. If you know where the bits are, it will let you fiddle with them. It's not the C compiler's job to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. That's what higher-level languages are for. A C programmer's version of a private member is a comment "/* Don't use this, it may change */"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an opaque type for this, two structs which start with the same fields and then you can add private fields to one of them and never let the user access the one with the private fields.

Then provide accessor functions to modify/read the private fields in the struct.

An example is better than a thousand words

**struct.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Private
{
    int public;
    int private;
};

struct Public
{
    int public;
};

struct Public *new_public(int private, int public)
{
    struct Private *instance;
    instance = malloc(sizeof(*instance));
    if (instance == NULL)
        return NULL;
    instance->private = private;
    instance->public  = public;

    return (struct Public *)instance;
}

int public_get_private(struct Public *public)
{
    if (public == NULL)
        return -1; /* or some invalid value */
    return ((struct Private *)public)->private;
}

void public_set_private(Public *public, int value)
{
    if (public == NULL)
        return;
    ((struct Private *)public)->private = value;
}
```

**struct.h**

```
#ifndef __STRUCT_H__
#define __STRUCT_H__

struct Public
{
    int public;
};

typedef struct Public Public;

Public *new_public(int private, int public);
int public_get_private(Public *instance);
void public_set_private(Public *instance, int value);
/* you can add more fields to the structures and more access functions */

#endif
```

**main.c**

```
#include "struct.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    Public *instance;

    instance = new_public(1, 2);
    if (instance == NULL)
        return -1;
    printf("%d\n", instance->public);
    printf("%d\n", public_get_private(instance));

    free(instance);

    return 0;
}
```

1. `new_public()` acts as a constructor.
2. You can get the value at `private` by means of the function `public_get_private()` which behaves as a member function.
3. You can't access the `private` member from the `Public` struct.

Of course you can do stupid things like

```
Public *public = malloc(sizeof(*public));
```

but thats what I find so sweet about c, you are free to do whatever you want, just don't do things wrong.

I also think this is nicer than `private` members, because both the definition and the implementation details are hidden from the library user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to accomplish this in the same way that C++ does. You can define a pointer to an opaque (i.e., incomplete) type, and use that to get data hiding. But to get private data members, you would need some kind of hack.

If you are satisfied with a hack, one way is to define a union type in the private implementation file to provide names to unnamed members implied in the public header file.

```
/* header.h */
struct X {
    char private[SIZEOF_Y];
};

/* implementation.c */
struct Y {
    int private_a;
    float private_b;
};

union Z {
    struct X x;
    struct Y y;
};
```

This is a hack because type punning is being used across incompatible types `X` and `Y`. There is also no clean way to communicate the `SIZEOF_Y` value to the header file, although you may be able to automate its definition with a script that runs before compilation of the source files.